# ArgumentMatcher for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito, argument-matching

I'm trying to use ArgumentMatcher in my tests. I do next:

```
Mockito.`when`(someRepository.save(
        argThat { it.name == someName } // Here I want to do mock for all objects with name someName
    )).thenReturn(save(someEntity))
```

And I get next error: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  `when`(p0: T!): OngoingStubbing!

How properly write ArgumentMatcher in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by adding ArgumentMatcher from java class. My IDE converted it to Kotlin:

In java:

```
Mockito.when(someRepository.save(ArgumentMatchers.argThat(entity-> entity.getName().equals("someName")
            && entity.getDescription().equals("somedescritpion")
            ))));
```

In Kotlin:

```
Mockito.`when`<Any>(someRepository.save(ArgumentMatchers.argThat { (name, _, description, ) ->
        (name == "someName" && description == "somedescritpion"
                )
    }))
```

Note: You should add _ if you have some fields which you don't want to consider in the matcher.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend using [nhaarman's mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) instead of vanilla Mockito. It has numerous advantages that allow it to be used with fewer issues in Kotlin as Mockito is designed for use in Java. You can see [this guide](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Mocking-and-verifying#argument-matchers) for how to use argument matchers in Kotlin. Your example will look very similar, but should have less issues with type inference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `someRepository.save(Mockito.any<String>())` . That would not care about what argument you are passing as long as it is a `String`. Empty values count too.