# Kotlin Argument Matcher failing with exception

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I have the followign bit of code which is failing in the arguents mismatch error

```
       mockSpotAccessor.doWithRetry(eq({
            mockSpotAccessor.asyncNestedAggregation(any(), any(), any(), any(), any()) }), eq(5))

        verify(mockSpotAccessor, times(1)).doWithRetry(eq({
            mockSpotAccessor.asyncNestedAggregation(any(), any(), any(), any(), any()) }), eq(5))
```

Expected
`spotAccessor.doWithRetry( (callRetryForAsyncCalls$2) () -> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<kotlin.collections.List<com.amazon.noblearsenallambda.AggregationResultObject>>, 5 );`

Actual
`spotAccessor.doWithRetry( (callRetryForAsyncCalls$answer$1) () -> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<kotlin.collections.List<com.amazon.noblearsenallambda.AggregationResultObject>>, 0 );`

I am not sure, as working with mockito for the first time

Answer (score 0):

1. The two lambdas cannot be expected to be `eq` (`equals`) to each other, even if the contents are identical, unless they refer to the exact same object reference.
2. When using matchers, matchers should only be used directly within the invocation for `when` or `verify` for all arguments to the call to `when` or `verify`. Because you're describing a lambda, the calls to `any()` don't happen as part of the call to `when` or `verify`, and therefore you should not use matchers.

The best shot you have is to use `any()` in place of the entire Unit or callback lambda, or possibly use an [ArgumentCaptor](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to capture the lambda, then invoke the lambda under controlled conditions and `verify` that it is invoked as you expect.

Comment: My lambda function definition is `fun <T> doWithRetry(action: () -> CompletableFuture<T>, retryCount: Int): CompletableFuture<T> {}`
.I f I passed any I get the error  `type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in 

fun <T> doWithRetry
(
action: () → CompletableFuture<T>,
retryCount: Int
)
: CompletableFuture<T>
Please specify it explicitly.`

Comment: @SakshiGarg That's a slightly different problem, but you can call `<List<AggregationResultObject>>doWithRetry(/*...*/)` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57256572/1426891).